# How to hide bootstrap modal in show.bs.modal event?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Here is a code example:

```
let order_modal = document.getElementById('order');

order_modal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(order_modal).hide();
}, false);
```

When I open the modal, it opens, the .hide() method does not work.

If I change event to 'shown.bs.modal' it works but modal blinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the `show.bs.modal` event from being executed :

```js
const modal = document.getElementById("modal");
        
modal.addEventListener("show.bs.modal", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"     crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal">
  Launch modal
</button>
  
<div class="modal fade" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button data-bs-dismiss="modal">
          Close Modal
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. A lot of work today, I forgot about it)))